# External Environment could not be started - CLR on Sybase's Interactive SQL

Tags: .net, sql, clr, sqlanywhere, isql

I'm having an issue figuring out how to start an external environment within Sybase Central's Interactive SQL. The executable, **dbextclr12.exe** has not been manipulated since 2010, so I know I didn't accidentally alter that.

Here is the call:

```
START EXTERNAL ENVIRONMENT CLR;
```

I just reinstalled .NET 3.5 and repaired 4.0.

```
Could not execute statement.
External environment could not be started, 'external executable' could
not be found
SQLCODE=-675, ODBC 3 State="HY000"
Line 1, column 28
You can continue executing or stop.
```

How do I get the External Environment to run?

Comment: You may want to post this question on sqlanywhere-forum.sybase.com, a Q&A forum dedicated to SQL Anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with ODBC. A path was changed in SQL Anywhere 12. Sorry for the PEBCAK, everyone.